# Make view with title and list of rows

Tags: c#, html, css, web

I want to make something like

[image]

but don't know how.the user can select multiple entries.any help would be great.

Comment: Try bootstrap multiselect plugins

Comment: maybe this helps you: [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use following class="selectpicker" for multiple select using bootstrap :

```
 <option>Mustard</option>
 <option>Ketchup</option>
 <option>Relish</option>
```

$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
  style: 'btn-info',
  size: 4
});